# Rails Model - custom primary key with ID as a custom column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I struggle with modeling my table to Rails model with **custom primary key** and `id` as a regular (not null) column.

The problem is my table has:

1. `auto_id` primary key column with AUTO_INCREMENT
2. `id` as custom column with `NOT NULL` constraint on it (it should be set by the application side before saving)

```
class InitialMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :cars, id: false, force: true do |t|
      t.primary_key :auto_id
      t.string :id, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I want to:

1. Make the `primary_key` being auto generated by database.
2. Set the `id` value directly in the application before saving the model.

But when I try to save a Car instance to database I have a problem with setting `id` from the app.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "auto_id"

  before_create do
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

Even in the `binding.pry` line, when I call `self.id = '1234'` it's being reassigned to `auto_id` field, instead of `id`.

Thus `id` columns always remain `NULL` which leads to a DB error `Field 'id' doesn't have a default value`.

```
[2] pry(#<Car>)> self.id = '9'
=> "9"
[3] pry(#<Car>)> self
=> #<Car:0x00007fcdb34ebe60
 auto_id: 9,
 id: nil>
```

PS. It's Rails 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid using `id` this way by renaming it to something else. In rails `id` is whatever the *@primary_key* is set to. There is a whole module dedicated to it, that defines *id* attribute methods:

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey.html*

These methods can be overridden, but shouldn't:

```rb
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = "auto_id"

  def id= value
    _write_attribute("id", value)
  end

  def id
    _read_attribute("id")
  end
end
```

"id" is [hardcoded](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.3.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb#L35) in *write_attribute* to use *primary_key*, so we can't use *write_attribute* to set *id* attribute itself.

Also, `id` methods are used in other places. Overriding them is a bad idea.

```rb
>> Car.create(id: "99")
=> #<Car:0x00007f723e801788 auto_id: nil, id: "99">
#                                    ^
# NOTE: Even though car has been saved, `auto_id` is still `nil`
#       but only in `car` object. Because we have overridden
#       `id`, primary key is read from `id` column and then `id` 
#       attribute is set in `id=`. `auto_id` is bypassed.

>> Car.last
=> #<Car:0x00007f774d9e8dd0 auto_id: 1, id: "99">

# NOTE: Other methods are broken whenever `id` is used

>> Car.last.to_key
=> ["99"]
>> Car.last.to_gid
=> #<GlobalID:0x00007f774f4def68 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://stackoverflow/Car/99>>
```

A better way is to not touch `id` methods:

```rb
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = "auto_id"

  def id_attribute= value
    _write_attribute("id", value)
  end

  def id_attribute
    _read_attribute("id")
  end
end
```

```
>> car = Car.create(id_attribute: "99")
=> #<Car:0x00007fb1e44d9458 auto_id: 2, id: "99">

>> car.id_attribute
=> "99"
>> car.id
=> 2
>> car.auto_id
=> 2
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! The idea with "id_attribute" is a pretty neat I would say!